# Cloudformation not creating EC2 instance, even though defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following CloudFormation template which is working fine apart from the fact that it is not creating the EC2 instance, below is the output I get from the Amazon GUI when running the configuration through CloudFormation:

```
2015-01-05  Status  Type    Logical ID  Status Reason
17:30:47 UTC+0000   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  Chris-Test-1    
17:30:45 UTC+0000   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::RDS::DBInstance    Failover    
17:24:13 UTC+0000   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::RDS::DBInstance    Failover    Resource creation Initiated
17:24:11 UTC+0000   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::RDS::DBInstance    Failover    
17:24:09 UTC+0000   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup   DBSecurityGroup 
17:24:05 UTC+0000   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup   DBSecurityGroup Resource creation Initiated
17:24:04 UTC+0000   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup   DBSecurityGroup 
17:24:02 UTC+0000   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup WebSecurityGroup    
17:24:01 UTC+0000   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup WebSecurityGroup    Resource creation Initiated
17:23:45 UTC+0000   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup WebSecurityGroup    
17:23:42 UTC+0000   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  Chris-Test-1    User Initiated
```

My CloudFormation configuration can be found at: https://gist.github.com/dayvo/817969702a589590c342

Any help getting the EC2 instance created would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously incorrect in your template and I am *very* surprise to not read any error message or warning.  To debug this, I would start to simplify, i.e. remove the CFN INIT section and user data, run the template again. When the EC2 instance will be created, progressively add sections again

Comment: I've had that section of EC2 code working fine before so I'm not sure it's that, since it was last working I've been trying to add the RDS instance in but that seems to be what is causing these problems, alsmost as though it can't create both the EC2 & RDS instances, which is strange.

Comment: It is possible to have RDS and EC2 instances in the same CFN template.  But you can remove the RDS instance and see what will happen. Did you switch Region or AWS Account since your last successful attempt ?  What is the output of 'aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS recently announced a "fix" for CloudFormation template validation coming in March 2015. Apparently, the JSON parser for CloudFormation won't catch or throw errors if a JSON object property is duplicated. This is exactly what is happening in your case.

See the resource named `ChrisFailover`. You're initially giving it a property called `Type` of `AWS::EC2::Instance`. Later on, in the same object, you're specifying `Type` again, but this time it's `AWS::RDS::DBInstance`. Same thing for the `Properties` property.

So essentially, your EC2 properties are being overwritten by the RDS properties for this one object. If you put your template into a JSON validator tool, such as http://jsonlint.com/ then you'll notice your EC2 data disappears.

To fix, make sure your RDS object is it's own resource.

Insert:

```
},

"ChrisDBInstance" : {
```

before:

```
"Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
```

EDIT: I was incorrect about the announcement. It was for IAM policy documents. But the problem is the same: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2718VHAGDHG09/Coming-March-2015-Upgrades-to-IAM-Policy-Validation